# chromium embedded framework CEF3 cross-compile for arm

Tags: arm, chromium-embedded

Can anyone share a complete list of steps to be performed in order to cross compile CEF3 for ARM?

I am working on host = ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to cross compile for odroid board.

This is the list of steps I performed:

```
>git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
>export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
>mkdir CEF3_odroid
>cd CEF3_odroid
>mkdir chromium
>cd chromium
>fetch --nohooks chromium --nosvn=True
>#I found the following revision reading CHROMIUM_BUILD_COMPATIBILITY.txt from https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src
>gclient sync --revision 14bd12d63019fbdd6f9d6c16b986a5f64a21264b --jobs 16
>cd src
>git clone https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef.git
>sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
>sudo apt-get install g++-4.8-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf
>./build/install-build-deps.sh --arm
>cd cef
>export GYP_GENERATORS='ninja'
>export GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1
>export GYP_DEFINES='target_arch=arm arm_float_abi=hard component=shared_library linux_use_gold_flags=1'
>./cef_create_projects.sh
```

And I got the following error: gyp: Call to 'python cups_config_helper.py --libs /media/varesio/disco2/GEF/CEF3_odroid/chromium/src/chrome/installer/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot' returned exit status 1. Traceback (most recent call last): File "tools/gclient_hook.py", line 106, in RunAction(cef_dir, gyper) File "/media/varesio/disco2/GEF/CEF3_odroid/chromium/src/cef/tools/gclient_util.py", line 39, in RunAction command, cwd=dir, always=True) File "/media/varesio/disco2/GEF/CEF3_Linux/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 293, in CheckCallAndFilterAndHeader return CheckCallAndFilter(args, **kwargs) File "/media/varesio/disco2/GEF/CEF3_Linux/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 538, in CheckCallAndFilter rv, args, kwargs.get('cwd', None), None, None) subprocess2.CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/bin/python ../build/gyp_chromium cef.gyp -I cef.gypi' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /media/varesio/disco2/GEF/CEF3_odroid/chromium/src/cef

Thanks Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem. Resolved by adding `use_cups=0` to `GYP_DEFINES` env.